# jpackage'd Java application on Windows does not find classes in the included jar files

Tags: java, windows, jpackage

I package my application with jpackage and the resulting directory structure and config file looks correct.

```
19.11.2023  15.49    <DIR>          app
19.11.2023  15.49           562 688 EazyCNC.exe
19.11.2023  15.49    <DIR>          runtime
               1 File(s)        562 688 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  417 389 883 392 bytes free
```

```
Directory of C:\Users\nyholku\eazycnc-build\bundle\EazyCNC\app
 
19.11.2023  15.49    <DIR>          .
19.11.2023  15.49    <DIR>          ..
19.11.2023  15.49               262 .jpackage.xml
19.11.2023  15.49           385 091 commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
19.11.2023  15.49               653 EazyCNC.cfg
19.11.2023  15.49         3 421 155 EazyCNC.jar
19.11.2023  15.49             4 928 humble-video-all-0.3.0.jar
19.11.2023  15.49         1 509 440 jna-5.6.0.jar
19.11.2023  15.49         2 735 878 jna-platform-5.6.0.jar
19.11.2023  15.49        11 712 967 jogamp-fat.jar
19.11.2023  15.49            65 966 json-20200518.jar
19.11.2023  15.49           195 713 miglayout-3.7.jar
19.11.2023  15.49           199 631 purejavacomm-1.0.1.x.jar
19.11.2023  15.49           118 138 purejavahidapi-0.0.13.jar
19.11.2023  15.49           127 628 vecmath.jar
              13 File(s)     20 477 450 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  417 401 921 536 bytes free
```

The app/EazyCNC.cfg looks like

```
[Application]
app.mainjar=$APPDIR\EazyCNC.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\humble-video-all-0.3.0.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\jna-5.6.0.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\jna-platform-5.6.0.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\jogamp-fat.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\json-20200518.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\miglayout-3.7.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\purejavacomm-1.0.1.x.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\purejavahidapi-0.0.13.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR\vecmath.jar
 
[JavaOptions]
java-options=-Djpackage.app-version=1.0
java-options=-Xmx1024m
java-options=-XX:+UseG1GC
java-options=-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50
java-options=-XX:+PrintGC
```

But when I try to launch it I get:

```
C:\Users\nyholku>eazycnc-build\bundle\EazyCNC\EazyCNC.exe
[0.004s][warning][gc] -XX:+PrintGC is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc instead.
[0.017s][info   ][gc] Using G1
Error: Unable to initialize main class eazycnc.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: purejavahidapi/InputReportListener
```

But when I use javajvm directly I like this:

```
C:\Users\nyholku\eazycnc-build\bundle\EazyCNC>java -cp app/* eazycnc.Main
```

it works.

I build the app using ant as follows (I've included only the relevant bits):

```
<target name="jpackage-windows" if="is_windows" depends="init">
    <exec executable="${jpackage}" dir=".">
        <arg value="--win-console" />
        <arg value="--type" />
        <arg value="app-image" />
        <arg value="--verbose" />
        <arg value="--dest" />
        <arg value="${bundle-dir}/" />
        <arg value="--name" />
        <arg value="EazyCNC" />
        <arg value="--main-jar" />
        <arg value="EazyCNC.jar" />
        <arg value="--java-options" />
        <arg value="-Xmx1024m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:+PrintGC" />
        <arg value="--resource-dir" />
        <arg value="${resource-dir}" />
        <arg value="--input" />
        <arg value="${jpackage-input-dir}" />
        <arg value="--runtime-image" />
        <arg value="${java-runtime-dir}" />
        <arg value="--temp" />
        <arg value="${build-dir}/wix-tempfiles" />
    </exec>
```

Some of the build variables are set like this:

```
    <property name="app-image-type" value="exe" />
    <property name="jdk-loc" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11" />
    <property name="jpackage" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\jpackage.exe" />
    <property name="jlink" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\jlink.exe" />
    <property name="targetos" value="windows" />
    <property name="pathsep" value=";" />
    <property name="resource-dir" value="package-resources/windows" />
```

and some other vars have these values (from my ant output):

```
     [echo] os.name           : Windows 10
     [echo] jdk-loc           : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
     [echo] fxant-loc         : ${fxant-loc}
     [echo] basedir           : C:\Users\nyholku\eazycnc-project
     [echo] build-dir         : C:\Users\nyholku/eazycnc-build
     [echo] lib-dir           : ./lib
     [echo] src-dir           : ./src
     [echo] dist-dir          : ./downloads
     [echo] temp-dir          : C:\Users\nyholku/eazycnc-build/temp-dir
     [echo] classes-dir       : C:\Users\nyholku/eazycnc-build/classes
     [echo] eazycnc_version   : 2.0.39
     [echo] jpackage-input-dir: C:\Users\nyholku/eazycnc-build/jlink-input
```

I'm using the jpackage from jdk21 as jdk11 does not have it, but I would not think that is a problem.

I've been stuck at this for a day now, what am I missing?

Comment: It might be time to add some debugging code.  I would print out `System.getProperty("jdk.module.path")` and `Main.class.getModule().getLayer().configuration().modules()`.

Comment: I don't think my main gets executed at all unless strip every reference to the classes in the jars it depends on ... which would not be a fun thing to do.

Comment: Ah, good point.  In that case, does `java -p app/ --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH eazycnc.Main` work?

Comment: I realised that if I just create an other class in the project with  main function that does not reference any of the missing classes then I can get that to run and thus do some more debugging as @VGR sugested.

Comment: You are building an appimage, but that is only one of two parts. Where is the command line that finishes your installer (.exe or .msi)? Without having run the installer and the executable stub I guess the APPDIR environment variable is not set.

Comment: @queeg You maybe on the right track with APPDIR not being set. But whose responsibility it is to set that and how should I fix this if all I want is .exe file that just works and don't want an installer.

Comment: It is the exe's job to set the directory. However I do not know how it works internally. Is it possible that the installer adds information where the executable is installed so it can set the APPDIR?

Comment: Maybe first confirm it works as intended (with installer). Only then check if you can (ab)use the appdir.

Comment: @queeg As explained in my own answer (below) it works it the --type is msi

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that

```
jpackage --type exe
```

just does not work for me. The resulting exe works but no classpaths apart from the main .jar seem to be set.

However

```
jpackage --type msi
```

does work.